# Is caching a good idea? If so, where?

Tags: asp.net, iis, caching

I have an asp.net web site with 10-25k visitors a day (peaks of over 60k before holidays). Pages/visit is also high, since it's a content site.
I have a few specific pages which generate about 60% of the traffic. These pages are a bit complex and are DB heavy (sql server 2008 r2 backend).
I was wondering if it's worth "caching" a static version of these pages (I hear this is possible) and only re-render them when something changes (about once in 48hs).
Does this sound like a good idea? Where would be the best place to implement this?
(asp.net, iis, db)

**Update:** Looks like a good option for me is outputcache with SqlDependency. I see a reference to some kind of SQL server notification for invalidating the cache, but I only see talk of SQL server 2005. Has this option been deprecated by Microsoft? Any new way to handle this?

Comment: Did this pages have any part dynamic or they all static data ? Eg, have any part of user names, or how many users are online ?

Comment: @Aristos - Nope. We don't have a membership system. We only use membership on one specific physical aspx file, which is not accessed much and it's our own implementation.

Comment: @Jackson Pope - Thanks for the edit :)

Comment: Then go use the most easy way of cache that comes with asp.net, just delcare <%@ OutputCache Duration="200" VaryByParam="*"  %>

Comment: @Aristos - And if I don't want the "dumpping" to be time based? Are there any other options? Like through a change to the DB or a programatic trigger? Will this actually keep a static version of the aspx (in HTML) in memory? No DB calls, etc?

Comment: I am looking at SqlCacheDependency to "dirty" the cache. Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caching is a broad term that can happen at a number of different points. The optimum solution may be a combination of some or all.

For example, you can add page, or output caching as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bh14hk.aspx), which caches output on the web server, which I think is what you were referring to.

In addition, you can cache the data in memory using something like [memcached](http://memcached.org), so that your data is more available to the web server as it builds the page, but you need to look at cache hit rate to know for sure that you are caching the right data.

Also, although slightly off the topic of improving db heavy pages, you can cache static resources that change infrequently like images, css and include files using a content delivery network. Any CDN will almost certainly have a higher bandwidth and a cheaper data plan than your own connection because of the economies of scale, so the more of your content you can serve from there the better, in general.

Your first question was "I was wondering if it's worth "caching" a static version of these pages". I guess the answer to that depends on  whether there is a performance problem at the moment, and where the cause of that problem is. If the pages are being served quickly and reliably, then quite possibly it's not worth implementing caching. If there is a performance problem, then where is it? Is it in db read time, or is it in the time spent building the page once the data has been returned?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think I'm looking at caching at the web server level. Memcached and CDNs are a great solution, but seem to be for higher volume sites (IMO), with distributed web servers, etc. I think they are both over the top for me right now.

Comment: Having re-read your question I've added another paragraph. Hope that helps.

Comment: In terms of the DB, I decided the best use of my optimization time / cash is to make sure everything is cached. Since the entire DB is about 300MB and growing very slowly, I just added another 2GB of ram and I'm getting very high numbers for foundincache. The main issue now is the construction of the page itself. Since it is made of several usercontrols, rendering takes a large chunk of the request handeling time. p.s. Thank you for taking the time to edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience in caching, but this is what I would try to do:

- I would look at your stats and run some profiles, see which are the most heavily visited pages that run the most expensive SQL queries.  Pick one or two of the most expensive pages.
- If the page is pseudo static, that is, no data on it such as your logged in username, no comments, etc etc, you can cache the entire page.  You can set a relatively long cache as well, anything from 1 min to a few hours.
- If the page has some dynamic real time content on it, such as comments, you can identify the static controls and cache those individually.  Don't put a page wide cache on.

Good luck, sounds like a cache could improve performance.

Comment: First point: I already did my home work :) Second point: I would rather the dirtying of the cache not be time based. Third point: I see you can define the caching at a per usercontrol level. Since most of the page is composed of different user controls, I can cache some and not others, if need be.

Answer (score 1):

Caching may or may not help. For example, if a site has low traffic and if the caching is enabled, the server processes to create the cache before serving the request. And because the traffic is low, there can be enough delay between successive requests. So the cached version may even expire and the server again creates a new cached version. This process makes the response even slower than normal.
[Read more: Caching - the good, the bad](https://adityabajaj.com/caching-the-good-the-bad/).

I have myself experienced this issue.

If the traffic is good, caching may help you have better load times.
Cheers
Aditya