# OutputCache with SqlDependency

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, caching

Continuing my research on asp.net caching.
From comments on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550490/is-caching-a-good-idea-if-so-where), I arrived at the conclution that the best caching method for my needs is the built in OutputCache of asp.net.
I saw that this directive includes a SqlDependency option and that has a CommandNotification option. Looking in to that, I found only talk of SQL Server 2005.

Has this option been deprecated?

Is there a better option?

What I'm looking to do is cache a page as long as the underlying data has not been changed.
I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 as the backend to the site.